# ASP.Net MVC multi record save

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm writing an mvc5 application where I have a model called Survey.

```
 public class Survey
{
    public int SurveyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Classification { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public int Score1{ get; set; }


    [Required]
    public int Score2{ get; set; }

    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

I'm passing a collection of Survey records to a view where I display them in a list. I want to be able to allow the user to answer each survey record/question and have a save button at the bottom of the form to conduct one POST action back to the controller.

I've never tried to pass a collection of objects back to the POST controller so I'm curious if this is a good approach?  Any suggestions is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest is not passing a collection to the view but a new ViewModel 'SurveySet' with perhaps its only field being IList(Survey). Then in the Controller when you call db.SaveChanges() on the surveySet and all the changes to each of its Surveys should be saved.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateComment(SurveySet surveySet)
{
db.Entry(surveySet).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
}
```